# upload image and showing the info

Tags: php, file-upload

I was trying to upload a picture file and I wanted to display the information of that picture. But my code is not working, I'm not sure what's the problem, I hope someone could point out what am I doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Image</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload_image.php" action="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image: <input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Now">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

   echo $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   echo $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
   echo $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
   echo $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

   if($image_name == ""){
        echo "<script>alert('Please select an image!')</script>";
        exit();
   }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

ps: I'm still new to php and file upload, so please go easy on me..Thank you in advance

Comment: what version of php are you using ?

Comment: Exactly @Fred-ii- he is missing the location to where it should be moved.

Comment: what does echo $_FILES['image']['error'] output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the fact that you didn't specify any location to where to upload it, neither the file type. Here is the code with Extension verification, Size, and moving the file in a folder called images.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
    $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");        
    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file."
    }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: while making sure the folder has proper permissions to write to ;-)